# PhantomJS is not animating gifs during load for screen capture

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to take screenshots of a lot of web pages.  Some of these web pages have short animated gifs on them.  No matter how long of a timeout I use between loading a page and using page.render, I still just get the first frame of the gif.  Is there anyway to make phantomJS run the gif animation?

Comment: Did you by any chance ever come to a resolution for this issue?